# What is the best way to convert WKT String to GML String

Tags: convert, geotools, gml, well-known-text, jts-topology-suite

What is the best way to programmatically convert WKT String to GML String? Every reasonable library (at best available in some Maven repository) can be used.

Till now I came up with this solution using JTS. Its written in Java:

```
public String wktToGml(String wktGeometry) {
   WKTReader wktR = new WKTReader();
   Geometry geom = wktR.read(wktGeometry);

   // write JTS to string
   GMLWriter gmlW = new GMLWriter(true);
   String gml = gmlW.write(geom);
   return gml;
}
```

But I'm not sure if it's the correct and most effective way. There are probably some problems with LF (linefeed) symbols. Probably there should be also a solution using geotools library.

I'm new to this field, I'm trying to gain some overview.

Comment: do you want a full GML document or just the gml:Polygon (or whatever) fragment?

Comment: probably just gml:Polygon

Comment: then you are probably fine with what you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly cleaner way of doing this with the option of GML 2 or 3 output is:

```
public class WKTToGML {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
    System.out.println(WKTToGML2("POLYGON((1 0,1 1,0 1,0 0,1 0))"));
    System.out.println(WKTToGML3("POLYGON((1 0,1 1,0 1,0 0,1 0))"));

  }

  static public String WKTToGML2(String wkt) throws IOException, ParseException {
    WKTReader wktR = new WKTReader();
    Geometry geom = wktR.read(wkt);

    org.geotools.xml.Configuration configuration = new org.geotools.gml2.GMLConfiguration();
    org.geotools.xml.Encoder encoder = new org.geotools.xml.Encoder( configuration );
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    encoder.encode(geom, GML._Geometry,out);
    return out.toString();

  }
  static public String WKTToGML3(String wkt) throws IOException, ParseException {
    WKTReader wktR = new WKTReader();
    Geometry geom = wktR.read(wkt);

    org.geotools.xml.Configuration configuration = new org.geotools.gml3.GMLConfiguration();
    org.geotools.xml.Encoder encoder = new org.geotools.xml.Encoder( configuration );
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    encoder.encode(geom, org.geotools.gml3.GML.geometryMember,out);
    return out.toString();

  }
}
```

gives the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><gml:Polygon xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><gml:outerBoundaryIs><gml:LinearRing><gml:coordinates>1.0,0.0 1.0,1.0 0.0,1.0 0.0,0.0 1.0,0.0</gml:coordinates></gml:LinearRing></gml:outerBoundaryIs></gml:Polygon>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><gml:geometryMember xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:sch="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><gml:Polygon srsDimension="2"><gml:exterior><gml:LinearRing srsDimension="2"><gml:posList>1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0</gml:posList></gml:LinearRing></gml:exterior></gml:Polygon></gml:geometryMember>
```